# Out-of-the-box app-engine connected android project not working -- app crashes

Tags: android, google-app-engine, osx-mountain-lion, eclipse-juno, gae-eclipse-plugin

I have been following to the letter the simple tutorial on [Creating an App Engine Connected Android Project](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae) using the eclipse plugin.

After setting up everything, running the project leads to two possibilities:

- If `LOCAL_ANDROID_RUN = false`, the project spits out the expected complaints:

  1) Registration with Google Cloud Messaging...SUCCEEDED!
  2) Registration with Endpoints Server...FAILED

  Either your Cloud Endpoints server is not deployed to App Engine, or  your
   settings need to be changed to run against a local instance by setting
   LOCAL_ANDROID_RUN to 'true' in CloudEndpointUtils.java.
- If `LOCAL_ANDROID_RUN = true`, the second I click "register" the app crashes! This is the part I don't get. I am running the project right out of the box. The only thing I did was change `LOCAL_ANDROID_RUN` from false to true.

So I have been researching for the past four hours on a resolution. I see talks about `-a 0.0.0.0` or `-bindAddress 0.0.0.0`; unless I am setting them incorrectly (I probably am), they are not working. Sometimes I get the "error" below. So if that's my problem please, what exactly am I supposed to have in the argument box before I click `apply` and `run`?

```
Options:
 --help, -h                 Show this help message and exit.
 --server=SERVER            The server to use to determine the latest
  -s SERVER                   SDK version.
 --address=ADDRESS          The address of the interface on the local machine
  -a ADDRESS                  to bind to (or 0.0.0.0 for all interfaces).
 --port=PORT                The port number to bind to on the local machine.
  -p PORT
 --sdk_root=DIR             Overrides where the SDK is located.
 --disable_update_check     Disable the check for newer SDK versions.
 --generated_dir=DIR        Set the directory where generated files are created.
 --jvm_flag=FLAG            Pass FLAG as a JVM argument. May be repeated to
                              supply multiple flags.
```

Any insights on how to get this `out of the box` project to work?